# Create a new object array based on jQuery result set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which contains a list of people. I want to query that table and produce a new array of objects which I will pass into an AJAX call.

So far I have this:

```
var result = $("table tr").not(":has(th)").each(function() {
    return { Id: 0, IsLead: 0 };
});
```

Assuming a table with 3 rows, my expected value for `result` would be:

```
[{ Id: 0, IsLead: 0 }, { Id: 0, IsLead: 0 }, { Id: 0, IsLead: 0 }]
```

Instead, `result` contains the elements which match the jQuery selector.

I'll be providing proper values to `Id` and `IsLead` based on data in the row, but to keep things simple I've excluded that here.

I'm obviously missing something fundamental in my approach.  I've tried searching existing questions but maybe I'm not phrasing it correctly as I can't find anything else similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `map`, not `each`

```
var result = $("table tr").not(":has(th)").map(function() {
    return { Id: 0, IsLead: 0 };
}).get();
```